# Value: Error Could not Convert string to float while using Sklearn Feature Relevance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ipython, feature-selection

Hello I have trained and tested data. I am trying to use sklearn's feature relevance Seelct K Best to choose relevant features and draw a bar graph after. However i get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: B
```

But i am starting to think I do have a column in my dataset looking like this which may be the issue:

```
CancellationCode:
A
B
C
D
```

If this column is causing a problem how do I resolve this error 
Here is my code below:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

selector = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=13)
selector.fit(X_train, y_train)

scores_select = selector.pvalues_
print scores_select


# Plotting the bar Graph to visually see the weight of each feature
plt.bar(range(len(scores_select)), scores_select, align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(features_columns)), features_columns, rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert categorical variables to dummies.

```
 df = pd.get_dummies(df)
```